# Conditionally grabbing column headings in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with many columns and indexed by probability.  Below is code that can generate a sample df

```
import numpy as N
probs = N.arange(0, 1, .1)
data = N.random.random_integers(0, 500, (10,3))
df = DataFrame(data, index=probs, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

I want to grab the column headings where the counts in the cells are above some threshold for specific probabilities.  For example, if I care about probabilities >=.75 and have values in the cells above 100 I can do the following

```
df[df['Probability'] >= .75] >= 100
```

But based on that indexing, how do I get the column headings where **at least one entry is True**?  (i.e 'col1' has at least one value indexed by a probability higher than .75 and greater than 100, not necessarily all of them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a boolean vector to columns axis of `.loc`.  For example, if you want columns where all values are above 100, your mask would be:

```
In [111]: mask = (df[df.index > .75] >= 100).any()
```

Then you can pass this to `.loc` to filter.

```
In [112]: df.loc[:, mask]
Out[112]: 
     col1  col2  col3
0.0   358    30   241
0.1   330    71   119
0.2   311    92   204
0.3   347   245   344
0.4   214   219   347
0.5   152   241    65
0.6   232   487    61
0.7   478   314   196
0.8   477   317   291
0.9   303    99   342
```

If you just want the column headings, you can apply the mask to itself.

```
In [119]: mask[mask].index
Out[119]: Index([u'col1', u'col2', u'col3'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: This isn't quite giving me the behavior I was looking for.  I want all the columns where AT LEAST ONE value is above 100, not necessarily all of them.  I've edited my question to make this more clear

Comment: @sedavidw - change `all()` to `any()` (I've edited the answer too).  I used `all` just to show the technique, because `any` doesn't  actually filter anything in this case.